# Find & Replace each word in various files with different Criteria in batch mode

Tags: ms-word

How can I apply multiple search criteria to the document for obtaining a refined result/search? I 'tried' using wildcards **->**   *?[!a-z][!0-9][!^s]*    **<-** to find a character except from range a-z, range 0-9, and the non breaking space(^s). i.e. I do not want to find any character, any number or a space, but tabs, operators, special characters, etc. At least that's what I think it does. How can I use multiple "find what" criteria together in a document?

Comment: Answer is urgently appreciated!

Comment: I would guess whether the question might be a bit easy or hard if somebody comments...

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, use wildcards and

[!0-9,a-z,A-Z, ]

should help. It may be possible to refine that further, but if not, VBA or equivalent and either a character-by-character check or multiple find loops are your options.

Comment: Thanks for the same. But how can i use the same you suggested including the "enter" characacter(as in ^p) and all using wild card. I have less knowledge about the same in VBA. How can i carry out the latter you suggested?

Comment: The syntax for wildcards is different. It's all explained in Word help (somewhere!). But for example, you should be able to add ^p to the list using ^13 instead, and some other marks are also detectable that way. As for the VBA thing, there are many, examples of using Word VBA to find things, here in StackOverflow and elsewhere on the web. I suggest you look through the tour at http://stackoverflow.com/tour before continuing as it will give you an idea about what people here expect.